# Developing an audio game with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, keyboard

I just released an audio version of a game for the blind and the sighted. I developed the game in C++/Qt because that's the language/framework I know the best, and because this is my first audio game, I want to stick with what I know best.

I don't know if this is a problem, but even if the game is audio-only with keyboard controls, it shows a full-screen empty mainwindow. That's because I kinda assume writing a console-only game with keyboard controls without QtWidgets package is really hard.

So here's my question: Am I right? I mean, is there an easy way to write a console game with keyboard controls with Qt? Or should I just forget about it and continue showing an empty window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your right.
With qt you will not be able to capture input in a useful way with console only.
since no gfx you can make the window very small.
you do however need to make sure the window keep focus so going full screen might make sense even.
you can consider displaying something in the windows just so other people can see that your game is running because an empty window very often seem like a chrashed app

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected as an answer.